# What are best practices for monitoring the OpenEthereum (Parity) logging?

Tags: private-blockchain, security, logs, openethereum

Monitoring of the logging output of the Ethereum clients is essential for stable blockchain operation.

**Do you have recommendations, experiences and/or lessons learned
concerning the logging of OpenEthereum/Parity nodes working with PoA?**

Interesting aspects are:

- What are proper setting for the log levels an why? What modules should be
  included in the logging?
- How to detect serious issues like network split, syncing problems and/or security related attacks?
- Do you know already prepared solutions for standard monitoring tools (like Splunk,
  Kibana) available?
- Are there regular expressions to filter interesting aspects?
- How are Testnetworks like Kovan monitored?

Not in scope for this question:

- Network Dashboards (e.g. Ethstats)
- Block Explorers
- Ethereum Event Exploreres